# Docker fluentd | Unable to forward request from host to docker deamon

Tags: docker, fluentd

I'm trying the run fluentd docker example following https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/install-by-docker

Unable to make request to the container. Hitting with the below error.

```
$curl -X POST -d 'json={"json":"message"}' http://localhost:9880/sample.test
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I tried to telnet:

```
$ telnet localhost 9880
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Looks like the docker container is running successfully:

```
$ docker run -p 9880:9880 -it --rm --privileged=true -v /tmp/fluentd:/fluentd/etc -e FLUENTD_CONF=fluentd.conf fluent/fluentd
2018-04-09 12:41:18 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf"
2018-04-09 12:41:18 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type http
    port 9880
    bind "0.0.0.0"
  </source>
  <match **>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</ROOT>
2018-04-09 12:41:18 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.1.3 pid=7 ruby="2.4.4"
2018-04-09 12:41:18 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/usr/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/usr/bin/fluentd", "-c", "/fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf", "-p", "/fluentd/plugins", "--under-supervisor"]
2018-04-09 12:41:19 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.1.3'
2018-04-09 12:41:19 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="**" type="stdout"
2018-04-09 12:41:19 +0000 [info]: adding source type="http"
2018-04-09 12:41:19 +0000 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=17 ppid=7 worker=0
2018-04-09 12:41:19 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2018-04-09 12:41:19.135995928 +0000 fluent.info: {"worker":0,"message":"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made all steps in the example. No errors, everything works good.
Check if 9880 port is open ( `netstat -neta |grep 9880` ).
Maybe you have a firewall (windows) or some iptables rules.
It seems a firewall problem. Please check it.